# Digest::SHA and utf8

Tags: perl, utf-8, digest

I have utf8 data which I pass to DIGEST::SHA on the following manner :

```
my $sha1=Digest::SHA->new;  

foreach (@fields ) {  $sha->add($record)       }
        print $sha1->hexdigest;
```

but i get unexpected behavior and every time i get different digest for the same record i read on http://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA that there are side effects of using Digest SHA with UTF8 
i trying the following metigation but both not works :

```
{use bytes;

foreach (@fields ) {  $sha->add($record)       }
        print    $sha1->hexdigest;
 }
```

and

```
 use Encode qw(encode_utf8);
  foreach (@fields ) {  $sha->add((encode_utf8($record))       }
        print    $sha1->hexdigest;
```

any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information about what's in `$record` and where it came from to answer your question.

Comment: the record come from db and its json encoded with json encode subrotine

Comment: Never use `use bytes;`. See its docs. /// It's not clear what two things generate different hashes, so it's there's really nothing to go on.

Comment: The above code doesn't make sense. You're adding the same thing (`$record`) to the hash function once for every field. Is it supposed to be `$record{$_}`?

Comment: Also, when you say that you have UTF-8 data in the strings, can this UTF-8 data be encoded into Latin-1 or not? Since you're not dying, I assume that it can be encoded in Latin-1. If so, then is there a reason you think UTF-8 is actually the problem? Does this code work on Latin-1 strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your actual data (e.g. `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $record;`) and what SHA you expect, it is hard to help.

That said, you may find the easiest way to get a consistent SHA is to force the json encoding to output only ASCII and make sure it always puts hash elements in a consistent order:

```
use JSON;
$serialized = JSON::to_json( $data_structure, { 'ascii' => 1, 'canonical' => 1 } );
```